# Render in IE 9 and Firefox, Totally Different

Tags: jquery, firefox, doctype, internet-explorer-9

http://beta.yigitaydogan.com/

I'm designing a web page which contains a lot of jquery animations in it and I had never tested it with IE during the development.

Now, I wanted to test it with IE 9 and just observed that it renders it in a totally different.

Is there any easy way to fix it to work in both ? All site is client side and it is on the link above.

Thanks,

Comment: Way too general/vague. You could pay someone to fix for you, or you could try it yourself and come back with specific problems/issues.

Comment: Not really helpful I guess, but... that background image is *huge*, make it smaller; and there is PHP in a comment inside your HTML

Comment: Did you put a DocType in your page? If not it can bring too a mess

Comment: it could be easyly seen when you try it with both browsers. At least the megamenu should be simple for those who experienced before.

Comment: Also, please clarify. What are the differences you see? Which behaviour do you expect, and what does IE do instead? Without a clear step-by-step guide to reproducing the problem, people won't be able to help you much.

Comment: @tdammers the megamenu (the main navigation) It doesn't show up in IE 9.

Comment: @Kubi - Your background image is 1.2MB and loading the entire page is almost 4Mb!!! You need to do something about that too.

Comment: @Geoff and other friends. This is just beta, I'm doing this for a friend of mine. Here my concern is about the layout and the animations which dont work in IE like it works in FF.

Answer (score 2):

Get some developer tools for IE and see if, by any chance, the `#oe_overlay` div ends up behind the background. `position: fixed` should cause it to be in front of regular-flow elements, but IE is known to be buggy with these things. Maybe adding a positive z-index to the oe_overlay div solves it. (I'm not on windows right now, so I'm making guesses here).

Also note that you're running in quirks mode - remove the comment at the top of the output and check your doctype. Chances are IE behaves correctly when not in quirks mode.

Answer (score 2):

The second part of the answer of @tdammers has it.

Remove the massive comment at the top of the source code which happens to be PHP code.

The best way to do this is to use PHP comments instead:

```
<?php
/*
    //your PHP code here
*/
?>
```

To be clear, the first line of your HTML output must be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

When you've done this, your XHTML doctype will take effect, and you will escape from [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) into Standards Mode, and **your site *is fixed* in Internet Explorer**.

---

Also, you said:

> I had never tested it with IE during
>   the development.

This is a big, big mistake. You should test your site in the lowest Internet Explorer version you want to support periodically during development.

Answer (score 1):

I know that IE8 renders differently sometimes (for example intranet sites) because there is an IE7/IE8/IE8 Compat mode.  This is all based on the doc type in the html.

If you open up the "web developer" (F12) you should be able to see what "mode" IE is running in.

I know that by default, IE8 renders in Compat mode if it determines that the site you are trying to visit is an intranet site.  I suspect this is because Sharepoint still renders that way, or something like that.

Anyways, give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Your question implies the hidden existence of a bigger problem - that you haven't yet done any cross-browser testing for your site. Many browsers will render slightly differently, and in IE's case, each version renders very differently.

As the others have said, your question is very wide-ranging. However, I think the most helpful thing for you would be to make you generally aware that the Mozilla browsers, the webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari), IE 9, IE 8, IE 7 will all behave differently.

One approach to testing your site across all these browsers might be to use a browser-testing service such as Browsershots.org.